# Using versioning on a VM with several users

Tags: mysql, github, architecture

We are looking for a way to use GitHub on an internal system that we are developing at work. We have developed it in PHP and MySQL, with a fair bit of jQuery/Ajax, on a Windows Server VM running IIS. Other staff can access the frontend over the network using the IP address.

There are currently three people working on it and at the moment we directly edit the file on the VM as we need it to still communicate with the database to check our changes have worked. There is no option to install anything like WAMP on our individual machines and there are the usual group policy restrictions so the only access we have to a database is via the VM. We have been working with copies of files/folders and the database but there is always the risk that then merging these would be a massive task.

I do use GitHub (mainly desktop but I can just about get by with using the command line as long as I have a list of the command in front of me) at home to sync between my PC and Laptop, via GitHub.com and believe that the issues we get with several people needing to update the same file would be eradicated by using it here at work.

However, there are some queries we need to ensure we have straight in our heads before putting forward a request.

1. Is what we are asking for viable? Can several branches on the same server be worked on at the same time or would this only work on an individual machine.
2. Given that our network is fairly restricted, is there any way that we can work on the files on our machine and connect to a VM hosted database? I believe that an IDE will allow us to run php files on a standard machine (although a request for Eclipse is now around 6 weeks old and there is still no confirmation that we will get it any time soon) but will this also allow .
3. The stuff we do is not overly sensitive but the company would certainly not want what we do out there in a public repository (and also would not be likely to pay for a premium GitHub account) so we would need to branch/pull/merge directly from our machines to the VM.

Does anyone have any advice/suggestions/solutions to this?  Although GitHub would be a preferred option as I already use it, we are open to any suggestion that will allow three people, on different machines, simultaneously work on a central system while ensuring that we do not overwrite or affect each others stuff.

Comment: Read up on GIT, It is not necessary to have a central repo. X people can collaborate quite happily without one.

Comment: Run away... 6 weeks to install eclipse and nothing has happened? You'll get old there before you can do anything meaningful and it will take you years to take the red tape gloom from your skin.

Comment: Checkout the [Forking Workflow talked about here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. It gives me a bit to look at, which I will do when back at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a git repo on Windows is not trivial and may require a fair bit of work. You can try using SVN it is fairly straight forward to install on windows and has a better learning curve than Git. I am not saying SVN is better/worse as compared to Git, it's much better suited to your needs. We have a similar setup and we use Tortoise SVN https://subversion.apache.org/ as a client. SVN also has branches and stuff. 
SVN for server side repository https://subversion.apache.org/

If you would still prefer Git on windows, check this out - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/step-guide-setup-secure-git-remote-repository-windows-nivedan-bamal

1) It is possible to work on many branches and then merge them into a single branch. That's the preferred Git development way. You can do the same on SVN.